# Are pure [database] ([mysql] and [sql]) questions still on topic on SO when there is dba.stackexchange for it?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question

dba.stackexchange.com says:

> Database Administrators Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for database professionals who wish to improve their database skills and learn from others in the community.

This covers almost all database tags that stack overflow has/had. This confuses the users as to what questions related to database should be asked here on SO and what questions gets fit on dba. If a database related questions are On-Topic on both sites, then what specifically led to creation of dba.stackexchange.com?

The unclear distinction for db related question between two sites raises several questions:

1. Shall flags be raised for questions that are purely database related on SO to migrate them to dba?
2. Which db related questions on SO to be marked off topic in context and which to consider on topic?

Am I missing something?

Comment: Imo, They are on topics here and some advance question can be on topics on Dba. But question are not some kids after a divorce. So and Dba wont figth over it. The 1rst one that get one of those have to keep it. If we start moving question because it's more on topics somewhere else then the musical chairs games begin

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It doesn't look like you [understand their scope](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), if I had to pick something that you were missing...

> If you have a question about...
>
> - Database Administration including configuration and backup / restore
> - Advanced Querying including window-functions, dynamic-sql, and query-performance
> - Data Modelling and database-design, including referential-integrity
> - Advanced Programming in built-in server-side languages including stored-procedures and triggers.
> - Data Warehousing and Business Intelligence including etl, reporting, and olap …then you're in the right place to ask your
>   question!
>
> but, dba.se is *not* the right place to ask questions about...
>
> - Client-side programming - ask on Stack Overflow
> - Basic SQL - ask on Stack Overflow
> - Career advice, including salary or résumé - try Patrick McKenzie's Don't call yourself a programmer

Stack Overflow gets the rudimentary SQL questions, the kind of questions that full-stack developers would experience and be able to deal with.  DBA.se gets the kinds of questions that DBAs have to handle *in detail*, and aren't equipped to handle basic SQL questions (copied verbatim from their FAQ).

So...

- If you see a question that's fairly basic in scope asking about SQL on Stack Overflow, **leave it here.**
- If you see a *good* question that's more about the administration of a database than about writing queries, you *might* want to think about migrating it.

Comment: That's where It confuses me: *basic* SQL- basic isn't a tangible word--What _basic_ means for one does not necessarily means for other..and therefore he tend to get confuse. For example, being a full stack developer, I find making db table relations basic but for fresher it is advanced.."Basic" tends to change more on the basis of experience and op's understanding

Comment: Think "basic" on the terms of, "would a DBA be doing this, or would a developer be doing this?"

Comment: Let me add that a question doesn't become off-topic due to the existence of another SE site where the question might *also* be on-topic. Ask yourself *Is the question on-topic here?*. And that is determined in our help and our meta.